# How to configure Entity Framework on Unity 3d

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-game-engine

I download `Entity Framework 6.1.3` through NuGet in vs 2017, the package manager place EF files in `\packages`, then I copy `\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40` to `\Assets\Plugins`, got this error,

`Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.`

After searching, someone suggest set `API Compatibility level` to `.NET 2.0 subset`, this don't work.

Is it possible to use `Entity Framework` in `unity3d`?

Comment: Did you find the solution?